# how to display image to background to tableview Cell

Tags: iphone

I want to display background image on tableview cell... on that i need to display my data.

How to do that?

@thanks in advance... Any proficient help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u want set background image for your table or for individual cell in UITableView
If it is for setting the background image then do the following:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background.png" ofType:nil]];
UIColor *bgColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:bgImage];  self.view.backgroundColor = bgColor;    
[tableName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

where tableName is the name of your UItableView

If you want to set background image for UITableView cell then do the following:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *cellBG_tap = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image.png" ofType:nil]]];
cell.backgroundView = cellBG_tap; 
[cellBG_tap release];
```

Comment: Also set the cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] before setting backgroundColor for the cell

Comment: @ swapna Thanks                                                         -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
 cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
 cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
 cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sapphire Square.gif"];
} -used above code which worked .thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

set a class on the cell, then use CSS to put the background image in, like below:

```
<table class="myTable">
 <tr>
   <td class="myCell"></td>
 </tr>
</table>

<style>
  .myCell {
    background: url(my_image.gif)
  } 
</style>
```

Comment: Pretty sure @kiran meant using a UITableViewCell, not web page.

Comment: This question is tagged under "iPhone", not HTML or CSS.

Comment: my bad. should have red more carefully.

Comment: displayed image on tableviewcell  ... but my data is not visible ... i thought to set Opacity for image view... Is this is a correct way to do ....

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify the UITableViewCell's contentView. For example:

```
//Add custom objects to the cell in here!
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];

imageView.center = CGPointMake(310, 48);
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
cell.textLabel.text=@"test";
```

Answer (score 0):

set background image as

```
   UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:img];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Square.gif"];

}
```

in table view data source

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image..."]];
cell.backgroundView=img;
[img release];
```

I used this its working  .... @all Thanks people for contributing your knowledge